# calling Amazon S3 from WCF service

Tags: amazon-web-services, wcf, amazon-s3

I try to upload an image from my WCF service to Amazon S3 web server. I have the Amazon S3 code that is working in a web project and my image upload method that is uploading image in Uploded\test.jpg in WCF service. I am not sure how I can use Amazon S3 code  working with WCF service. 1st I don't know how to put Amazon credential in the web confing when I add these line of code inside the  it is not uploading:

```
    <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="myaccessKey"/>
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="MySecretKey"/>
</appSettings>
```

and this is my method to upload to the WCF server I guess I have to add AWS code when I said //AWS here:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadImage", Method = "POST")]
    Stream UploadImage(Stream request)
    {

        Stream requestTest = request;

        StreamWriter sw = null;


        string logpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Uploded\\logtest.txt");

        logpath = logpath.Replace("SSGTrnService\\", "");


        HttpMultipartParser parser = new HttpMultipartParser(request, "file");

        string filePath = "";


        string passed = parser._content;

        string sLogFormat = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString() + " ==> ";
        sw = new StreamWriter(logpath);


        sw.Flush();


        if (parser.Success)
        {


            // Save the file somewhere 
            //File.WriteAllBytes(FILE_PATH + title + FILE_EXT, parser.FileContents);

            // Save the file 
            //SaveFile( mtp.Filename, mtp.ContentType, mtp.FileContents);
            FileStream fileStream = null;
            BinaryWriter writer = null;


            try
            {


                filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Uploded\\test.jpg");  // BuildFilePath(strFileName, true);    





                filePath = filePath.Replace("SSGTrnService\\", "");

                fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);

                fileStream.Write(parser.FileContents, 0, parser.FileContents.Length);

                // return filePath;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            return "Error: " + ex.Message;

            }
            finally
            {

                if (fileStream != null)
                    fileStream.Close();
                if (writer != null)
                    writer.Close();
                //AWS Code



            }
        }

        //
        // returning text for html DOM
        //

        string text = "Image uploaded: " + parser.Filename + " / " + parser.ContentType + filePath + passed;
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encoding.GetBytes(text));
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
        return ms;
    }
```

Any Guide in calling Amazon S3 from WCF service would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a amazon dll that you would need to reference (AWSSDK.dll) and then use the below lines of code:

```
var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(accessKey, secretKey);
var bucketName = "Files";
transferUtility.Upload(filePath, bucketName, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
```

NOTE: Please make sure that the Amazon S3 bucket "Files" exists. Else you need to check if the bucket exists and then perform the upload method call. Hope that helps.